# Strange behavior with unconventional passing of arguments

Tags: php, function, default-arguments

I accidentally copied the function header when calling a function in my code, and for some reason the code still works. Why is this?

```
$data = Utilities::multi_curl($substance_year_combo_groups, $files = false, $download_folder = null, $file_name = null, $pop = false, $handle_key = 'results');
```

Obviously, it's supposed to be written like this:

```
$data = Utilities::multi_curl($substance_year_combo_groups, false, null, null, false, 'results');
```

But I can see in my debugging that the last parameter indeed is `'results'`. Shouldn't a pure variable assignment just be evaluated as `true`?

The `$handle_key` is `null` by default in the function header.

Comment: No, a variable assignment 'evaluates' as it were, to the value of the variable.  That's why you can do something like `if($myVar = myFunc($myParam) === $myOtherVar){//do something}`.

Comment: @PatrickQ you should definitely post that as an answer

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat The current answers are more thorough. My comment really is just that. I rarely feel that simple yes/no answers require more than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered, but to include a reference from [PHP: Assignment Operators Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is 3.

Comment: The simplest answers are the best. Thank you, I should've known that this was the case, but for some reason I'm certain that there programming languages where an assignment is evaluated as `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments get evaluated, and the results of those evaluations are passed in.

Remember that in PHP assignments have a "return value", which is the value that was assigned.

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo;
$result = some_function($foo = 'blah');
echo $foo;
```

This code will echo out `barblah`, and pass `blah` into `some_function` as the argument.

This is the exact same mechanism that allows:

```
$a = $b = $c = $d = 42;
```

to work, and assigns `42` to all four variables.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the assignment operation is the value being assigned. For instance, I can do this:

```
if($result = do_something_that_may_fail()) {}
```

Whatever the `do_something_that_may_fail()` method returns will be assigned to `$result` and, if that anything that doesn't evaluate to false, the `if` block will be executed.  A byproduct of this is that you can still reference `$result` inside of the `if` block.

The same thing is happening in your method call, the values are being assigned and the value itself is being sent to the method.